# Is there a scenario where you should manually set object property as undefined?

Tags: javascript

Since in JavaScript, every uninitiated property returns undefined.

```
var a = {b:1};
a.x; // Undefined
```

Then to check if value exists or not, it's common to do this:

```
if (a.x !=== undefined) {..
```

I know `hasOwnProperty` is the better choice. However, you do find code that does the above, or simply `!!a.x`.

This is a problem. Now you don't know whether the value didn't get assigned or the value was assigned, but what was being assigned was empty.

Given this fact, should it be considered a bad practice to do the following anytime...

```
a.x = undefined;
```

Or are there situations where this is required or even preferred?

Answer (score 2):

To remove a property of an Object

```js
delete a.x;
```

I wouldn't say setting `a.x = undefined` is bad practice, if the goal is to set it to `undefined`.
But if used to simulate removing a property, it is.

Answer (score 2):

One difference is that values set with `undefined` will still show up when using a for-in loop, or when using `Object.keys()` while unset or missing values will obviously not show up.

Personally I would use `null` for values that are purposefully supposed to be empty or uninitialized since `null` is valid in JSON while `undefined` is not, but if you're not worried about that then you can use `undefined` to.

As a somewhat contrived example off the top of my head, this could be helpful to explicitly unset an object's variables through some kind of extend function that uses a `for-in` loop. Or alternatively you could use it to prevent overwriting certain variables.

Check out the following example:

```js
class MyClass {
  static greet(){
    if(!this.say){
      return console.log("I don't know how to greet")
    }
    if(!this.to){
      return console.log("I don't know who to greet")
    }
    console.log(this.say, this.to)
  }
}
MyClass.say = "Hello"
MyClass.to = "World"

function extend(klass, obj, canOverwriteWithUndefined){
  for(let key in obj){
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'undefined' && canOverwriteWithUndefined === false){
      throw "Cannot overwrite value with undefined key: " + key
    }
    klass[key] = obj[key]
  }
}

const a = { say : "Hello", to : "World" }
const b = { say : undefined, to : "StackOverflow" }
const c = { say : "Hello" }
const d = { to : undefined }

extend(MyClass, a)
MyClass.greet() // Hello World

extend(MyClass, b)
MyClass.greet() // I don't know how to greet

extend(MyClass, c)
MyClass.greet() // Hello StackOverflow

extend(MyClass, d, false)
MyClass.greet() // Error
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between an unassigned value and an empty value. By default the value is always undefined and your code should always check for undefined to avoid unwanted output.

If for some reason the value of the object's property has to be removed, you should set it to empty (like an empty string or numeric 0 or an empty object/array). So the code written using that property never fails.

If at all you need to set it undefined, you may delete the property itself from the object but that would mean, your code would need to check if the property exists using the hasOwnProperty method.

Comment: i prefer setting it to null, feels like less headache then empty string